# Carousel won't center its slides

Tags: jquery, center, carousel

I'm having an issue with my jQuery carousel: its slides won't get centered on the viewport when I click on the "next slide" button.

Instead, they will get placed 'somewhere' around the center, slightly misplaced, as jQuery seems to slide my images depending on the carousel's total width (I think).

Here's a test page I did for you to see it better:

http://paragraphe.org/stackoverflowdemos/slider-how-to-center-slides/

...and here's the code I'm using, taken from a WordPress theme. I played with it for some time and got to change some behaviours, but not my main concern.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#mainholder").css("width", "100%");
    jQuery("#mainindex").css("width", "100%");
    jQuery("#mainholder #holder div.singleitem").css({
        "margin-left": 10
    });
    jQuery("#mainholder #holder div.singleitem").last().addClass("last").css({
        "border-right": "10px"
    });
    jQuery("#mainindex #imagediv img").css({
        "margin-left": 0
    });
    jQuery("#mainindex #imagediv img").last().css({
        "margin-right": 0
    });
    totalwidth = jQuery("#holder").width(); // Total large image width          
    totalimages = jQuery("#holder .singleitem").size();
    totalwidth = totalwidth + (10) * (totalimages + 1);
    jQuery("#holder").css({
        "width": totalwidth
    });
    sliderwidth = 1;
    jQuery("#imagediv img").each(function () {
        sliderwidth = sliderwidth + parseInt(jQuery(this).attr("width")) + 1;
    });
    jQuery(".end").css("right", "0");
    if (totalimages <= 1) {
        jQuery("#mainholder").addClass("fixwidth");
        jQuery("#mainholder").css("width", "960px");
        jQuery("a.leftnav,a.rightnav").hide();
    }
    variablechange(); //for initialization before window resize is called
    function variablechange() {
        tempslidedist = new Array();
        slidedist = new Array();
        screenwidth = jQuery(window).width(); // Visible screen width
        handlewidth = ((screenwidth / 10) - 6); // width of the slider handle according to the width of the screen      
        screenmid = (screenwidth) / 2; // Middle of visible screen
        tempval = (screenmid * 10000) / (totalwidth); // The total distance the slider has moved when it reaches the middle of the screen.
        mval = totalwidth * .000095; //
        holdermulti = (totalwidth - screenwidth + 10) / 1000; // Multiple value with which the main images move     
        halfhandlewidth = handlewidth / 2;
        jQuery("#imagediv").css("width", (sliderwidth) + "px");
        indexwidth = (sliderwidth - handlewidth - 5);
        jQuery("#index").css("width", indexwidth + "px");
        divratio = (indexwidth) / 1000;
        if (sliderwidth > screenwidth) {
            jQuery("#index").css("margin-left", "71px");
        } else {
            jQuery("#index").css("margin-left", "");
        }
        slidespeed = (1000 / (sliderwidth)) * 95;
        if (sliderwidth < (handlewidth + 10) || totalimages == 0) { //+10 is added to make the difference larger so when they are almost same, the
            error doesnot takeplace
            jQuery("#mainindex").hide();
            jQuery(".slider-navigation a.leftnav, .slider-navigation a.rightnav").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery("#mainindex").show();
            jQuery(".slider-navigation a.leftnav, .slider-navigation a.rightnav").show();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < totalimages; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                tempslidedist[i] = ((jQuery("#imagediv img:eq(" + (i) + ")").width() - ((handlewidth + 3) / 2)) + (jQuery("#imagediv
 img:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").width() / 2) + 0);
            } else {
                tempslidedist[i] = (tempslidedist[i - 1] + jQuery("#imagediv img:eq(" + (i) + ")").width() / 2 + jQuery("#imagediv
 img:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").width() / 2 + 0);
            }
            slidedist[i] = Math.round(((tempslidedist[i])) / divratio);
        }
    }
    jQuery(".imgexcerpt").hide();
    jQuery(".imglink").mouseover(function () {
        jQuery("#mainholder").addClass("disablemove");
    });
    jQuery(".imglink").mouseout(function () {
        jQuery("#mainholder").removeClass("disablemove");
    });
    jQuery(".imgexcerpt").mouseover(function () {
        jQuery("#mainholder").addClass("disablemove");
    });
    jQuery(".imgexcerpt").mouseout(function () {
        jQuery("#mainholder").removeClass("disablemove");
    });
    jQuery(".imglink").click(function (e) { //Toggling the show/hide the img excerpt link   
        thisimgwidth = jQuery(this).parent().find("img").width();
        if (thisimgwidth < 355) {
            exceptwidth = (.85 * thisimgwidth);
        } else {
            exceptwidth = 340;
        }
        jQuery(this).parent().siblings().find(".imgexcerpt").fadeOut("fast").end().find("img").fadeTo("fast", 1).end().find(".imglink").addClass("show");
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("show")) {
            jQuery(this).parent().find(".imgexcerpt").css({
                "width": exceptwidth
            }).fadeIn("fast");
            jQuery(this).parent().find("img").fadeTo("fast", .3);
            jQuery(this).removeClass("show");
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent().find(".imgexcerpt").css({
                "width": exceptwidth
            }).fadeOut("fast");
            jQuery(this).parent().find("img").fadeTo("fast", 1);
            jQuery(this).addClass("show");
        }
    });
    jQuery("#index").slider({
        max: 1000,
        animate: true,
        step: 1,
        change: ifSliderChange,
        slide: ifSliderSlide
    });
    jQuery("#index").slider("value", (0));
    jQuery("#index").css("z-index", "99");
    mainfunctions(); //for initialization before window resize  
    function mainfunctions() {
        jQuery("#index .ui-slider-handle").css("width", (handlewidth) + "px");
        if (sliderwidth < screenwidth) {
            jQuery("#index .ui-slider-handle").css("margin", "0 -" + (handlewidth / 2 + 3) + "px");
        }
    }
    animating = false;
    click = -1;
    jQuery(".leftnav").live("click", function () {
        if (!animating && !jQuery("#mainholder").hasClass("disablemove")) {
            if (click >= 0) {
                click--;
            }
            var sliderpos = jQuery("#index").slider("value");
            var flag = 0;
            for (var j = totalimages; j >= 0; j--) {
                if ((sliderpos > slidedist[(j)]) && flag == 0) {
                    click = j;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (click < 0) {
                jQuery("#index").slider("value", (0));
            } else {
                jQuery("#index").slider("value", (slidedist[click]));
            }
            animating = true;
        }
    });
    jQuery(".rightnav").live("click", function () {
        if (!animating && !jQuery("#mainholder").hasClass("disablemove")) {
            click++;
            var sliderpos = jQuery("#index").slider("value");
            var flag = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < totalimages; j++) {
                if ((slidedist[(j)] > sliderpos) && flag == 0) {
                    click = j;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (sliderpos >= 1000) {
                jQuery("#index").slider("value", (0));
                click = -1;
            } else {
                jQuery("#index").slider("value", (slidedist[click]));
            }
            animating = true;
        }
    });
    jQuery(".end").css("z-index", "99");
    jQuery(".start").css("z-index", "99");
    jQuery(".end").click(function () {
        jQuery("#index").slider("value", (1000));
    });
    jQuery(".start").click(function () {
        jQuery("#index").slider("value", (0));
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        variablechange();
        mainfunctions();
    });

    function ifSliderChange(e, ui) {
        jQuery("#mainindex").animate({
            scrollLeft: (((ui.value - tempval) * mval))
        }, 500);
        jQuery("#mainholder").animate({
            scrollLeft: (ui.value * holdermulti)
        }, 500, function () {
            animating = false;
        });
    }

    function ifSliderSlide(e, ui) {
        jQuery("#mainholder").prop({
            scrollLeft: (ui.value * holdermulti)
        });
    }
});
```

Would you know a way to get the images on the viewport's center?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think one of the issues that you have or that might be contributing at least is the fact that you have a margin-left:10px on all the div's containing the images.  I think this is causing a calculation problem because when you scroll over all the way to the end it gets farther and farther off center (which could be 10px per time).  

Instead of doing thisimgwidth = jQuery(this).parent().find("img").width();

try 

thisimgwidth = jQuery(this).outerWidth(true);  *The true includes the margin of the element

Comment: @Peanuts: In the future, please properly format your code so others can read it easier. Also, that is a lot of code to ask people to look through. I recommend creating a simple example that demonstrates the *specific* problem you are having or, better yet, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: What are you doing to center them ? I dont see anything to center them. Your viewport (the width of screen is not fixed but the width of images are fixed (900px)

Comment: Thanks guys for your observations, I'm going to work further on this. Indeed, the progressive "misplacement" is 10px at a time (because of the margin?) so I could work on that direction. Also, it would be amazing if someone can suggest any tweak so instead of moving the images by their width -per click-, they slide to the center of the viewport.